# Java Keystore - Importing existing wildcard cert from a PKS file

Tags: java, keystore

To Red Hat **Linux** v6.5

I have been provided by our Windows team a Wildcard certificate for one of our domains that I need to use as a Java Keystore file for a project within Hadoop (Apache Flume to be exact).

The file is a password protected .PKS file. When extracting them into the Windows Cert store, it extracts 3 certs, those being the ROOT CA, the Intermediate CA and the actual wildcard cert itself.

When I attempt to install this on a Linux host it only appears to export out 1 certificate, with a completely different fingerprint ID than the one I see in Windows.

What am I doing wrong here? 
This is the import command I am using...

**keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore mynewwildcardcert.jks -srckeystore STAR_WildcardCertfromWindowsTeam.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12**

When I do a...
**keytool -list -keystore mynewwildcardcert.jks**
...I can only see one entry, which I assume is wrong, give I would think I would see 3 entries??

I'm assuming I am missing a trick with alias' here, but as I didn't generate a keytool request csr for it I have no point of reference here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I have found my own answer. This guide helped me a lot.

https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/626.html

I was already at this stage, but the -v option in the keystore -list command on the original Windows supplied .pks file helped me to check what I had in the original store versus what I ended up with in the imported Java Keystore file.

The fingerprint was actually the MD5 number.